# trust failure when trying to access my Kestrel-based REST server

Tags: rest, xamarin, .net-core, https, kestrel

I'm experimenting with a Xamarin app, which should access a .NET Core REST server.

I ran into this issue when switching to https; I can access the api from Chrome no problem, but if I try so from within my app, I get a `System.Net.WebException` saying

*'Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.)'*.

I setup my server like this:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUrls("https://*:5000")
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    return host as IWebHostBuilder;
}
```

and in my app, I do something like this:

```
public bool addUser(User user)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.1.79:5000/api/users");
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";

    try
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ecx)
    {
        var what = ecx.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: what does the inner exception say?

Comment: What's the authentication you're using on that endpoint? I'd guess you need to add something to the request.

Comment: Are you using a self signed cert? Is this Android or iOS it fails on? Also I highly suggest that you use HttpClient and it's async API so you don't block the UI.